Yerushalmi Kaftan
I am a satmer hasid, I live in Canada. I am of yerushalmi origins, my whole family lived there and I was born there. I have recently decided to start taking up yerushalmi hasidic customs as well. One thing I am interested about is where one can buy a real yerushalmi Kaftan?
Thank you.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya.
FYI - i believe that the custom of the Yerushalmi's is to only wear the yerushalmi garb in Israel. Outside of Israel they most usually wear regular Chassidic garb. One exclusion that comes to mind are Rebbe's and other community leaders who might keep the yerushalmi garb on even outside Israel. I am sure that you can easily find a store in Meah Shearim that sells such clothing. Online you will most probably not find it as the communities who wear this type of garb shun the internet.

Got it thank you, I plan on moving back soon IYH so I will just get one then once I will be living in yerushaloyim
